# Reading from second line in a text file

Tags: c#

This should be an easy one...for someone else.  I'm reading a text file with some values in it, and breaking those values down into individual values...blah blah.  Basically I need to know how to retrieve the value from the second line in my text file.  My code already reads the first value from the first line.  How do I repeat this process as I will have 20-30 different lines with different values on them?

```
namespace oSnaps
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // read the settings file and disect the value of OSMODE
        private String settingsPath = "N:\\C3D Support\\MySettings.txt";
        private enum oSnap : int
        {
            none = 0,                       // =0
            endpoint = 1 << 0,              // =1
            midpoint = 1 << 1,              // =2
            center = 1 << 2,                // =4
            node = 1 << 3,                  // =8
            quadrant = 1 << 4,              // =16
            intersection = 1 << 5,          // =32
            insertion = 1 << 6,             // =64
            perpendicular = 1 << 7,         // =128
            tangent = 1 << 8,               // =256
            nearest = 1 << 9,               // =512
            apparentIntersection = 1 << 11, // =2048
            extension = 1 << 12,            // =4096
            parallel = 1 << 13,             // =8192

            defaultmode = 1 << 0,           // =1
            editmode = 1 << 1,              // =2
            commandactive = 1 << 2,         // =4
            commandmode = 1 << 3,           // =8
            menumode = 1 << 4,              // =16

        }


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LoadSettings();          
        }
        private void LoadSettings()
        {
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(settingsPath))
            {
                try
                {
                    StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(settingsPath);
                    file.WriteLine("OSNAPS,0" + Environment.NewLine + "Mouse Value,0");
                    file.Close();
                }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("MySettings.txt was unaccessable.  Contact the IT Department if you see this message.");
                    return;
                }
            }
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(settingsPath);
            SetOsnaps(lines);
        }

        private void SetOsnaps(string[] lines)
        {
            try
            {
                // First line = lines[0]
                int val = Convert.ToInt32(lines[0].Split(',')[1]);
                if ((val & 1) == 1) { cbxEndpoint.Checked = true; }
                if ((val & 2) == 2) { cbxMidpoint.Checked = true; }
                if ((val & 4) == 4) { cbxCenter.Checked = true; }
                if ((val & 8) == 8) { cbxNode.Checked = true; }
                if ((val & 16) == 16) { cbxQuadrant.Checked = true; }
                if ((val & 32) == 32) { cbxIntersection.Checked = true; }
                if ((val & 64) == 64) { cbxInsertion.Checked = true; }
                if ((val & 128) == 128) { cbxPerpendicular.Checked = true; }
                if ((val & 256) == 256) { cbxTangent.Checked = true; }
                if ((val & 512) == 512) { cbxNearest.Checked = true; }
                if ((val & 2048) == 2048) { cbxApparent.Checked = true; }
                if ((val & 4096) == 4096) { cbxExtension.Checked = true; }
                if ((val & 8192) == 8192) { cbxParallel.Checked = true; }

                // Second line = lines[1]
                int mval = Convert.ToInt32(lines[1].Split(',')[1]);
                if ((val & 1) == 1) { cbxRcDefault.Checked = true; }
                if ((val & 2) == 2) { cbxRcEdit.Checked = true; }
                if ((val & 4) == 4) { cbxRcCommandActive.Checked = true; }
                if ((val & 8) == 8) { cbxRcCommand.Checked = true; }
                if ((val & 16) == 16) { cbxRcMenu.Checked = true; }

            }
```

Text file example:

val, 768

mval, 12

Comment: Does your `line` parameter contain just the first line of your text file, or the contents of the whole file?

Comment: We don't need to see `SetOsnaps` at all.  We need to see the code that is reading the lines from the file and calling `SetOsnaps`.  The idea is to pass the right data to `SetOsnaps`, not to modify `SetOsnaps`.

Comment: Edited my code sample

Comment: Thanks for updating your question to show how you are loading data into the `line` parameter.  It seems like you will not be able to access the second line of the text file within your `SetOsnaps` because you are only passing in the first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the context (a short file with only two lines) then you could simply read all lines from your file, then pass all of them to your function

```
private void LoadSettings()
{
    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(settingsPath))
    {
        try
        {
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(settingsPath, "OSNAPS,0" + Environment.NewLine + "Mouse Value,0");
        }
        catch 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("MySettings.txt was unaccessable.  Contact the IT Department if you see this message.");
            return;
        }
    }
    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(settingsPath);
    SetOsnaps(lines);
}

private void SetOsnaps(string[] lines)
{
   try
   {
      // First line = lines[0]
      int val = Convert.ToInt32(lines[0].Split(',')[1]);
      if ((val & 1) == 1) { cbxEndpoint.Checked = true; }
      if ((val & 2) == 2) { cbxMidpoint.Checked = true; }
      if ((val & 4) == 4) { cbxCenter.Checked = true; }
      if ((val & 8) == 8) { cbxNode.Checked = true; }
      if ((val & 16) == 16) { cbxQuadrant.Checked = true; }
      if ((val & 32) == 32) { cbxIntersection.Checked = true; }
      if ((val & 64) == 64) { cbxInsertion.Checked = true; }
      if ((val & 128) == 128) { cbxPerpendicular.Checked = true; }
      if ((val & 256) == 256) { cbxTangent.Checked = true; }
      if ((val & 512) == 512) { cbxNearest.Checked = true; }
      if ((val & 2048) == 2048) { cbxApparent.Checked = true; }
      if ((val & 4096) == 4096) { cbxExtension.Checked = true; }
      if ((val & 8192) == 8192) { cbxParallel.Checked = true; }

      // Second line = lines[1]
      int mval = Convert.ToInt32(lines[1].Split(',')[1]);  
      if ((val & 1) == 1) { cbxRcDefault.Checked = true; }
      if ((val & 2) == 2) { cbxRcEdit.Checked = true; }
      if ((val & 4) == 4) { cbxRcCommandActive.Checked = true; }
      if ((val & 8) == 8) { cbxRcCommand.Checked = true; }
      if ((val & 16) == 16) { cbxRcMenu.Checked = true; }

 }
```

Comment: Thanks a ton.  There is definitely still an issue though.  It doesn't appear to be reading the second line at all still.  It's simply using the first instance in both cases.  i.e. if val actually = 24 it reads mval as 24 also

Comment: Are you sure that the file contains just two lines without empty lines between? Did you check  the second indexer (`lines[1]`)? Please add a MessageBox(lines[0]) and another one MessageBox(lines[1]) before calling the SetOsnaps method

Comment: Updated my original post.  Yes there are currently 3 lines in the text file.  each line is a word a comma then a value of at least 0.  Hmmm...reading back over my code, it looks like I need another enumerator...

Comment: Well, thats right and add the appropriate decoding in the SetOsnaps using `lines[2].Split......`

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to read about reading from files? is seems not :/

```
bool isFirst = true;

using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
{
    while(!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        if (isFirst)
        {
            isFirst = false;
            continue;
        }

        SetOsnaps(reader.ReadLine());
    }
}
```